# Radio Button checked as default remains on true

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

Please help me try figure out why my radio button default checked remains to True.

Here is my js file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var is_display = $("#is_display_value").val();

  if (is_display) {
    $("#id_is_display_True").prop("checked", true);
    $("#id_is_display_False").prop("checked", false);
  } else {
    $("#id_is_display_True").prop("checked", false);
    $("#id_is_display_False").prop("checked", true);
  }
});
```

html:

```
<div class="status">
    <p>Status</p>
    <input type="hidden" value="False" id="is_display_value"> <!-- Value of {{is_display}} is based on Database, True or False -->
</div>
<div class="status status-body">
    <div class="status-choice">
        <input type="radio" class="triple" name="is_display" value="True" id="id_is_display_True">
        <label for="hide">Show</label>
    </div>
    <div class="status-choice">
        <input type="radio" class="triple" name="is_display" value="False" id="id_is_display_False">
        <label for="hide">Hide</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

[My JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rodjames/urkn4qmb/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you input value return a string (you case capitalized string )

first get the value string as

```
var is_display = $("#is_display_value").val().toLowerCase();
```

in your condition `if (is_display)` , it'll always return true because you check if the string `"True"` or `"False"` will always return true

you can fix that using one condition as :

```
  //get value to lower case 
  var is_display = $("#is_display_value").val().toLowerCase();
  
  $("#id_is_display_true").attr("checked", is_display == "true");
  $("#id_is_display_false").attr("checked", is_display == "false");
```

See below snippet :

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var is_display = $("#is_display_value").val().toLowerCase();
  
  
  $("#id_is_display_true").attr("checked", is_display == "true");
  $("#id_is_display_false").attr("checked", is_display == "false");
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="status">
    <p>Status</p>
    <input type="hidden" value="False" id="is_display_value"> 
</div>
<div class="status status-body">
    <div class="status-choice">
        <input type="radio" class="triple" name="is_display" id="id_is_display_true" value="true">
        <label for="hide">Show</label>
    </div>
    <div class="status-choice">
        <input type="radio" class="triple" name="is_display"  id="id_is_display_false" value="false">
        <label for="hide">Hide</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: *or* you could convert the .val() to boolean at time of extraction: `var is_display = $("#is_display_value").val() == "True"`

Comment: it's still a string if you .val() and thye value is "true", so toLowercase just helps with the comparison

Comment: Thank you. I have some small changes but it is working.

Comment: @freedomn-m tried with Boolean(is_display) always return true

Comment: Not sure why you tried `Boolean()` but you can read here why that won't work: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean

Comment: @freedomn-m yep passing string will always return true , could you describe how you did convert val() to boolean :)

Comment: It's in my comment above.  `var bln = str == "True"`

Comment: It's essentially saying:  `var bln = (str == "True" : true ? false)`